# Flutter Downloader plugin is not working in android version 9 and above in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have given all permissions but it is not working in 9 and latest all android device

[flutter downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader)

Comment: Check this there is an issue in plugin https://prnt.sc/wctyCzkbzQoe

Comment: Yes, I checked that. Thank you.  Is there any plugin to get device info. specially device version. Except device_info_plus plugin

Comment: No there is no other ways